# Using alphanumeric instead of INT in my primary key table. The table ID is going to be including A1, A2 or B1,C1

Tags: sql-server, alphanumeric

I am building this project with SQL Server.

I need to create a `Shop` table, this shop (numbers) will include alphanumeric as the shop's identification number.

How do I create a table with alphanumeric primary key instead of using `INT` as data type? And will this table still increment like when using `INT` for the primary key?

Comment: A key column is not limited to integers.

Comment: You should not make your primary key a human relevant key. Use a regular indentity column for your primary key and have the shop code as a secondary identifier.

Answer (score -1):

As for the data type, you can use "nvarchar" to be able to deal with letters and numbers, for increment you have to do it manually (either in code or in a function in the database)

Comment: You can, but it's not a good idea to do so.

Answer (score -3):

You can use guid and below is how you define your primary column.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Read more on guid [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)