# How do I create a table that will accept members to register their shops numbers as alpa-numeric as end-user

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I am working on Table called (Shops_Table).

This table will accept registration from the shops owners, some of these shops identifies  numerically (INT), Example... shop No 1, shop No 2, shop No3, and on 1000s.

And other shops identifies Alphanumeric (Char),Like shop No 1a, shop No 1b, shop No 1c,  shop No 1b and on 1000s

Now..

I found this code below here in stackoverflow, can is do the job??

DECLARE @Base10ToBase36 AS TABLE (
ID      TINYINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Symbol  CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(Symbol LIKE '[0-9,A-Z]')
)

INSERT INTO @Base10ToBase36(Symbol)
VALUES  ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9'),
('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('H'), ('I'), ('J'),
('K'), ('L'), ('M'), ('N'), ('O'), ('P'), ('Q'), ('R'), ('S'), ('T'),
('U'), ('V'), ('W'), ('X'), ('Y'), ('Z')

SELECT  TOP (1)
pos1.ID * 36 + pos0.ID AS Base10Number,
pos1.Symbol,
Pos0.Symbol,
CONCAT(pos1.Symbol, Pos0.Symbol) AS Base36
FROM    @Base10ToBase36 AS pos0
CROSS JOIN @Base10ToBase36 AS pos1
ORDER BY NEWID()    -- random

Comment: Keep your database key and your user key totally separate. Use identity for PK and string for user key.

Comment: You should have two keys. The natural key is the one which exists in the outside world. You could make that a string, a json object, whatever you like. Then, also have a surrogate key, used internally within the database, likely to also be your primary key and also likely to be an identity column.

Comment: Hang on, you already asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006815/using-alphanumeric-instead-of-int-in-my-primary-key-table-the-table-id-is-going